# Do web hosting companies typically charge extra for custom MX records?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, mx, namecheap

I bought a domain from one hosting company then I bought a email account from Namecheap and I want to set the email there so I need the mx records from the hosting company where I bought the domain. But they are asking money per year to give that information or to have access to it.

I changed many domains and emails and this never happened before.
Is this normal procedure?

Comment: You currently have a single company servicing your domain registration, DNS hosting, and web hosting?

Comment: Some companies may charge for "DNS Hosting", especially if you didn't buy the domain from them and don't have any other services.

Comment: You are mixing four different things. "I bought a domain" => that is through a registrar typically (provider 1).  "from one hosting company" => I guess you mean webosting it, so that is provider 2. Maybe they do DNS hosting too, but that is technically a separate job, provider 3. "I bought a email account" => that is an email provider, again a completely different job, provider 4. All those 4 providers can be a single company doing everything or 4 completely separate ones. But until all of that is clear nothing useful can be done.

Answer (score 2):

That is not normal procedure and sounds like a rip-off from what you have described.. Some registrars charge a premium for full DNS, however not for providing information or basic DNS service.  Why not just change your registrar and DNS to Namecheap and be done with it?

Comment: Then use Namecheap for DNS hosting too?

Answer (score 2):

It absolutely depends on their policy. Generally those that aim for a certain market of non-tech savvy users do offer a plan with little controls and then charge for mundane things like MX records. I've even had one ask for money to activate the 'firewall'!

This is *not* common practice for more reputable places and most - even very cheap solutions - will generally have an interface for customers to change custom MX records and provide free-of-charge support to change configuration not available in the self-serve interface.

The bottom line is that you *must* read and ask questions, if uncertain, exactly what  you are getting for the price advertised. There are all sorts of plans with arbitrary limits to distinguish each other even if there is no different in H/W and S/W required on the hosting provider's part!